# how to divide a hexagon into regular polygons

Tags: discrete-geometry, tiling

I want to cut a hexagon paper into regions of equal areas (more precisely either into squares of side c or into regular hexagons of side c). In both cases some of the papers will be wasted. Is it possible to know what is the best way to waste the minimum of papers? (Maybe something related to the Honeycomb conjecture?)

Comment: The best way to cover a hexagon is with a single congruent hexagon. The lost space is zero. Perhaps you need to clarify your question, and also link it somehow to mathematical research, which is what this MO website is about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually I should have used the word divide instead of cover!

Answer (score 5):

The answer will very much depend on whether squares or hexagons,
and how many.
For example, if you specify $7$ squares in a regular hexagon,
then these two arrangements are possible:

---

[image: HexSqs]

---

The partition on the right is superior (squares are larger; wastes less paper),
but I don't know if it is optimal.

***Update***. Here is an improved $7$-square packing, as suggested
by Aaron Meyerowitz:

---

[image: HexBetter]

---

Comment: On the right, you can push the top and botom two hexagons until they contact the middle 3. Then no square is touching the boundry so the squares can be enlarged somewhat.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few nontrivial examples of [hexagons in hexagons](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/hexinhex/):

[image]
[image]
[image]